# Adding to the Font Options in CKEditor 3

Tags: theming

I want to add a custom font to the font options for the [CKEditor](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module, but it doesn't work.

I added this in ckeditor/config.js.

[image: CKEditor config snippet]

I added this in ckeditor/font.css.

[image: ccs snippet]

However, my custom font doesn't show up in the CKEditor font menu.

[image: CKEditor font menu]

I'm working with CKEditor 3.6.

Comment: Instead of showing a screenshot of text, just copy and paste the text. Text in images is not parsed and indexed. This means this question has less chances to be found from people who has the same problem.